# Kernel Panic - Not syncing : VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)

Tags: grub, initramfs, dracut, panic

After updating more than ~1000 things my installation of RHEL 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.
I get the following kernel panic message:

> Kernel Panic - Not syncing : VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (0,0)

I am able to boot with the bootloader by selecting the previous version.

I've tried:

dracut -f initramfs-2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64.img 2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64

and:

`dracut --regenerate-all`

also my `grub.conf` file was missing initrd below the new (1st) kernel:

initrd /initramfs-2.6.32-754.23.1.el6.x86_64.img

So I added it. I still get the kernel panic afterwards.

I've tried to `yum update` on the old kernel and it will not update complaining about:

```
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.5.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libturbojpeg.so(TURBOJPEG_1.0)(64bit)
           Available: turbojpeg-1.2.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               libturbojpeg.so(TURBOJPEG_1.0)(64bit)
           Installed: turbojpeg-1.11-20081028.x86_64 (installed)
               Not found
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.5.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libturbojpeg.so(TURBOJPEG_1.1)(64bit)
           Available: turbojpeg-1.2.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               libturbojpeg.so(TURBOJPEG_1.1)(64bit)
           Installed: turbojpeg-1.11-20081028.x86_64 (installed)
               Not found
Error: Package: VirtualGL-2.5.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libturbojpeg.so(TURBOJPEG_1.2)(64bit)
           Available: turbojpeg-1.2.1-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               libturbojpeg.so(TURBOJPEG_1.2)(64bit)
           Installed: turbojpeg-1.11-20081028.x86_64 (installed)
               Not found


** Found 2 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
1:tcl-8.5.7-6.el6.i686 is a duplicate with tcl-8.4.13-4.el5.i386
1:tk-8.5.7-5.el6.i686 is a duplicate with tk-8.4.13-5.el5_1.1.i386
```

Since I updated the system originally, will the old kernel still need the 1000 updates?  In other words are the files that were updated the same files that the old kernel uses when booting?

Comment: What I'd like to know is - Is my old Kernal updated?

Answer (score 1):

> So I added it. I still get the kernel panic afterwards.

because `root=/dev/sd..` is still missing?

Comment: Missing from where?

Comment: @3dalliance  see my  comment in identical other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `root=/dev/sdXY` in your kernel arguments.

Comment: he is going to answer I tried both solutions and neither `sd..` nor `sdXY` worked. But I found the problem...

Comment: Please elaborate @rastafile

Comment: Please reserve comments for clarifications on the post.

Comment: I found the line in the anaconda grub.conf file and it was commented out but I don't know if it was commented out before the updates.  I un-commented it and it still panics on boot.