# Error after installation of slackware

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, slackware

After installation of slackware I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itEJJ.jpg).It happens just after fresh installation and [solution](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/boot-error-end-trace-4175521552/) mentioned here doesn't work. Tried reinstalling 4 times but same error.When booting with huge kernel I got [this error](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Snkdpznqvv1n7JZ48). Please let me know am I missing something??
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score -1):

Your first screenshot only shows "prepare_namespace" and "mount_root" functions as the last thing before panic.

The second one has the correct error message:

`VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block...`

I had the same problem, with different kernels; the kernel panics are very variable, depending on *how unable* the kernel is. In one word, it is the essential `root=` boot param that is not working, directly or indirectly.

---

One simple reason is mentioned here: [VFS: unable to mount root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546879/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block-0-0). This gives some context.

---

In my case it was the missing `initrd=` boot param. *Most* kernels need the modules from the initrd to access the disk.

I guess you booted and installed from a USB Flash with a slackware image. So it is only a configuration problem.

> Tried reinstalling 4 times

I know what you mean, and sometimes I try a fifth time, but then I try to take a systematic approach.

---

Here are the two kernel command lines I saved for booting slackware from Uefi Shell.

`slack\huge.s root=/dev/sda2`

and

`slack\huge.s initrd=slack\initrd.img`

Neither will work like that, though: it takes both paramters to work. Grub has an almost identical line.

This works:

`arch5\vmlinuz-linux initrd=arch5\initramfs-linux.img root=/dev/sda3`

And this also, only kernel that has the modules for SSD built in:

`fedora\vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2`

`slack`, `arch5` and `fedora` are just dirs I created to store the kernels and their initrds.

---

I see the tag `slackware` says: A linux based operating system.

I totally disagree with that, which may sound ridiculous, since I want to call it a linux distribution. But this site is called Unix&Linux and not Posix&Distros.

---

`mount_block_root()` in `init/do_mounts.c` has this (I deleted the #ifdefs):

```
                 /*
                 * Allow the user to distinguish between failed sys_open
                 * and bad superblock on root device.
                 * and give them a list of the available devices
                 */

                __bdevname(ROOT_DEV, b);

                printk("VFS: Cannot open root device \"%s\" or %s: error %d\n",
                                root_device_name, b, err);
                printk("Please append a correct \"root=\" boot option; here are the available partitions:\n");

                printk_all_partitions();

                panic("VFS: Unable to mount root fs on %s", b);
        }
        if (!(flags & SB_RDONLY)) {
                flags |= SB_RDONLY;
                goto retry;
        }

        printk("List of all partitions:\n");
        printk_all_partitions();
        printk("No filesystem could mount root, tried: ");
        for (p = fs_names; *p; p += strlen(p)+1)
                printk(" %s", p);
        printk("\n");

        __bdevname(ROOT_DEV, b);

        panic("VFS: Unable to mount root fs on %s", b);
out:
        put_page(page);
}
```

So the helpful error messages are there, but if the problem is the (missing) block device driver/module itself, it can break a bit anyhow - I really had all sorts of kernel panics with an incorrect kernel command line.

Comment: What else need to be done after running setup for installation of slackware;I don't think I should face any problems since setup command was successful or do I need to run other commands once setup is finished

Comment: "since setup command was successful": the way I remember slackware's install that is not so easy to tell, in the blue installation menu. The missing piece could be the bootloader/boot params.

Comment: Thanks for helping me !!! . I asked about the installation part as a separate question.