# What else is to followed for successful installation of slackware

Tags: linux, system-installation, slackware

What else apart from setup needs to be done for successful installation of slackware linux?

Background-
I installed slackware by simply running setup command and nothing else but after reboot I can't boot successfully ( [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560068/error-after-installation-of-slackware) are the errors which I faced;asked as a separate question ) So with that I think online available guides ( guides that is referred to [1st](https://www.unixmen.com/install-slackware-14-1-step-step/) [2nd](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/install-slackware-linux/amp/) )have missed or forgot to mention something important or some optional things are to be done if user needs features (like partition on which I am trying to slackware is a logical partition ). If anyone has successfully installed slackware please let me know what else needs to be done? Thanks in advance for help !!!

Comment: Have you managed to install it?

Comment: I gave up after trying many times but if you have found/or want to add an answer go ahead and I will try installing it again.

Comment: Is this UEFI or MBR system? What is your hardware spec? Can you boot to setup with no problem at all? Have you tried any other linux, like booting / installing KNOPPIX to confirm that this is only slackware related problem, but no your hardware specific issue no matter which linux you are trying to install?

Comment: MBR system , processor - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/36463/intel-core-2-duo-processor-e7300-3m-cache-2-66-ghz-1066-mhz-fsb.html ; 4GB ram ;Tried many linux dustro with all of them currently installed - debian,arch,fedora(had graphics problems),void,solus ; haven't tried KNOPPIX